# Change yValue label vertical spacing in combined chart (ios-charts)

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have a combined chart that uses a line and bar chart to show yValues.
In some instances the line and bar chart values will overlap, is there a way to set the vertical spacing of the labels for the yValues so that they're not on top of each other (like Jan to Oct in the image)?

[Combined Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bnIO.png)

I'm using the Charts framework (formerly ios-charts), here is the code to setup the CombineChartView:

```
        let xValues = getXAxisLabelsForYear(year)
        let runningTotalsByMonth = getRunningTotalByMonthForYear(year)!
        var yValsBar = [BarChartDataEntry]()
        var yValsLine = [ChartDataEntry]()

        for i in 0 ..< xValues.count {
            let yBarDataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: monthlyWinnings[i], xIndex: i)
            yValsBar.append(yBarDataEntry)
            let yLineDataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: runningTotalsByMonth[i], xIndex: i)
            yValsLine.append(yLineDataEntry)
        }
        let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: yValsBar, label: "Monthly Winnings")

        //setup bar chart
        var barChartColors = [UIColor]()
        for i in monthlyWinnings {
            if i >= 0.0 {
                barChartColors.append(myGreen)
            } else {
                barChartColors.append(UIColor.redColor())
            }
        }
        barChartDataSet.colors = barChartColors
        barChartDataSet.barShadowColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        barChartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)

        //setup line chart
        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yValsLine, label: "Cumulative Winnings")
        var lineChartColors = [UIColor]()
        for i in runningTotalsByMonth {
            if i >= 0.0 {
                lineChartColors.append(myGreen)
            } else {
                lineChartColors.append(UIColor.redColor())
            }
        }
        lineChartDataSet.colors = lineChartColors
        lineChartDataSet.circleColors = [UIColor.blueColor()]
        lineChartDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
        lineChartDataSet.circleRadius = 5
        lineChartDataSet.lineWidth = 2
        lineChartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)

        //combine data
        let data = CombinedChartData(xVals: xValues)
        data.barData = BarChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSet: barChartDataSet)
        data.lineData = LineChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)

        combinedChartView.data = data

        //format the chart
        combinedChartView.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0)
        combinedChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
        combinedChartView.descriptionText = ""
        combinedChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        combinedChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        combinedChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        combinedChartView.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = true
        combinedChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        combinedChartView.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout or setting the frames manually?

Comment: If you could post some more information about how you're setting these values, that would help too.. Are the bar and label / line dot and label in one view, are they all separate, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw bar chart values below the top of the bar using

```
chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
```

and setting some color

```
barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.someColor()
```

Will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above, but something like this may work if you're not using auto layout:

```
let labelA = UILabel()
let labelB = UILabel()

let padding: CGFloat = 5.0 // or whatever

if CGRectIntersectsRect(labelA.frame, labelB.frame) {
    // If the minY of labelA is <= labelB's that means labelA is ABOVE labelB
    if labelA.frame.minY <= labelB.frame.minY {
        // Set it above, with some (optional) padding
        labelA.frame.origin.y = labelB.frame.origin.y - padding - labelA.frame.height
    } else {
        labelB.frame.origin.y = labelA.frame.origin.y - padding - labelB.frame.height
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need additional code for checking if it's too high and other edge cases.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this is related to the Charts framework (formerly ios-charts). I've updated my question accordingly and posted the related code to generate the chart.